# Increment Key in a collection

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, key

I have a collection say

```
Map<Integer,Integer> myMap=new Map<Integer,Integer>();
myMap.put(1,"a");
myMap.put(2,"b");
myMap.put(3,"c");
```

My map currently has {1="a",2="b",3="c"}.
Suppose I want to put a value say `myMap.put(1,"d")`

So is there a way that I am able to add the existing key and incrementing the remaining key so my output map be like 
{1="d",2="a",3="b",4="c"} ?

Comment: Do keys have to be sequential? 'cause if so, it sounds like you're looking for an array / list instead of map (could also work if keys are not sequential and only order of values is what matters)

Comment: No! I have to stick to collection. Just to ask question I simplified the problem statement and yes keys has to sequentital.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to iterate over all the elements of the `Map` in order to modify the values for all the existing keys.

For example, woth Java 8 Streams you can produce a new Map where the keys are incremented, and then add the new Entry :

```
map = map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e->e.getKey()+1,e->e.getValue()));
map.put(1,"d");
```

However, if your keys are consecutive integers (as your example suggests), why not use an `ArrayList<String>` instead of a `Map<Integer,String>`? This will give you the functionality you want by simply calling `list.add(0,"d");` (with the small difference of the indices starting at 0 instead of 1).

Comment: Iterating over all elements and incrementing them one by one. Can you tell me how to implement that ?